# Parse Server SDK - Include Object method doesn't work for fetching the whole object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-server, back4app

I was using [parse server sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk) in my app for database.

I have three class in my Back4App Dashboard which are **"_User", "Office", "Office_Members"**.

In Office_Members class it has following columns,

1. user_id (Pointer to _User)
2. office_id (Pointer to Office)
3. count

To fetch the data including Pointer to _User as well from Office_Members, I am using following code,

```
QueryBuilder<ParseObject> parseQuery = QueryBuilder<ParseObject>(ParseObject("Office_Members"))
              ..whereEqualTo("office_id", ParseResponse_OfficeObject)
              ..includeObject(["user_id "]);

ParseResponse apiResponse = await parseQuery.query();
```

Output :

```
Payload : [{"className":"Office_Members","objectId":"twpDY51PUK","createdAt":"2020-08-14T09:58:59.775Z","updatedAt":"2020-08-14T09:58:59.775Z","office_id":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Office","objectId":"4dkfSMrwBI"},"user_id":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"Hx5xJ5ABxG"},"count":1}]
```

In my payload response i am not getting whole user_id pointer response.

So can anybody help me that what i might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I see a blank space at `"user_id "` could you please try to trim this string?

Comment: i have already removed it

Comment: So your problem is probably regarding permission. You probably do not have public read permission for this User object (either because of the CLP on _User class or ACL on this specific object). For security reasons it is recommended to keep your user class not public, so the best solution would actually be through cloud code.

Answer (score 1):

The data should be included.
The logging function simply does not print the data of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The data should be included. The print function not print the data of pointers.

You can print it out directly for testing purposes, E.g.

`response.results[0].get('user_id').get('name')`

[Evaluation Expression E.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izjM6.png)

---

In your model u can access at same way, E.g

Call Model

```
if(response.success){
  return response.results.map((p) => Example.fromParse(p)).toList();
} else {
  throw ParseErrors.getDescription(response.error.code);
}
```

Model

```
import 'package:parse_server_sdk/parse_server_sdk.dart';

class Example {

  Example({this.id, this.name});

  Example.fromParse(ParseObject parseObject) :
        id = parseObject.objectId,
        name = parseObject.get('user_id').get('name');

  final String id;
  final String name ;


  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Example{id: $id, name: $name}';
  }
}
```

Comment: exactly print function don't print pointer and can be fetched using model data or extracting directly. So basically its there but you didn't see in payload

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use cloud code ? I'm not to familiar with flutter but I can suggest you this alternative solution.
Write a function like this.

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("fetchMemberAndUser", async (request) => {
        //Pass in ParseResponse_OfficeObject ID as parameter
        var objectId = request.params.id;
    
        //Now do a simple get query
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("Office_Members"));
        //Using .includes to get the user profile object
        query.include("user_id");
        //This will return Office_Memebers Object along with user profile
        return query.get(objectId,{useMasterKey:true});
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to make curl requests. Also there is a ParseCloudFunction. But, there is no way to pass includeObject() method to ParseCloudFunction request anyway.

Comment: "But, there is no way to pass includeObject() method to ParseCloudFunction request anyway"

Could you explain this a bit more ? I'm not quite following you.